# Workload chunks with Airflow

Tags: airflow

is possible in airflow to split the workload in chunks? For example: if I have a file with 1.000.000 of records can process than in chunks of 100.000 each one and run these chunk parallelly.
I know that Celery has something called Chunks for this purpose, but I need the same in Airflow.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can create task dynamically in airflow, you can also use python in airflow and use it's multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow is primarily used for orchestration. You can do this by assigning the tasks dynamically in the DAG. However this is not an ideal use case. My recommendation would be to use Airflow to schedule the pushing on this data into messages queues like RabbitMQ or Redis.